# How does writing in ES6 and compiling to ES5 benefit the end user?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Much of the JS community have fully embraced the practice of writing in ES6, and using a compiler (such as Babel) to output more browser-friendly ES5.

My question is, if what runs in the browser is exclusively, or overwhelmingly, ES5, then in what way does the **user** benefit from all that additional JS? The extra code added by Babel makes the compiled app.js heavier and potentially less performant.

So I guess my question is - What's the point in all this?

You'll notice my question makes a few assumptions. Feel free to correct those **:)**

Comment: This is like asking "why would you use Java when you could use C"? It's because of the syntactic sugar. You get less buggy programs, and you can develop faster.

Comment: @4castle I suspected this may be the case, which is why I worded my question to specifically address the issue of how/if end users (as opposed to authors) benefit from this.

Comment: It does not benefit the user in any way. Any feature that a transpiler gives you, you can implement for your users yourself. The transpiler is there to benefit *you*, the developer. 

You write more concise, expressive code, that's easier to read and maintain.

Comment: The user is only benefited indirectly. If you use tools that make your programming cleaner and easier to maintain, it will benefit your users through lack of bugs and your speedy ability to push updates/bugfixes.

Comment: In other words, it helps you help them.

Comment: _"my question makes a few assumptions. Feel free to correct those"_  Anything that improves development benefits the user in some form (shorter release cycles, less bugs etc.). Moreover current browsers support ES6. Transpiling is more for backwards compatibility these days. Which also benefits the user, who is not required to install a current browser.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of benefits that help offset the cost of using a transpiler. The biggest one for me is that your code can have less bugs.

An example of an ES6 feature that will help your code be more stable is `let`. In ES5 and prior, using `var` to create variables has been plagued with bugs, due to variable hoisting. Var Hoisting is where you code executes differently than what you write. This is usually not an issue, but can be, especially with for-loops and variables inside of if-statements. However, now with `let`, we get actual block scoped variables. This means that those kind of bugs disappear, as `let` scopes it's variable to the currently block scope. It is pretty powerful, and in a way pathetic that it took JS this long to get.

Another example is `arrow functions`. While all JS developers know what an anonymous function is, an arrow function is almost identical, but has two major differences. First, arrow functions don't have a prototype, meaning that they have a lighter footprint in memory. The second is that `this` gets bound to the outer-scope with an arrow function, where anonymous functions lose all value and notion of what the outer-scope's `this` was. Using anonymous functions, you end up with a lot of bugs, cause you reference variables on the `this`, but `this` is undefined. So to fix it, people end up doing silly things like `var me = this;` and then they reference `me` in the anon function callbacks. Having arrow functions will make your code less buggy and easier to maintain.

So, due to things like `let` and `arrow functions`, and many others, the code you write in ES6 has more potentially to be more semantically correct than ES5 code, which should result in more stable code.

Perhaps my favorite feature is classes. It is so much easier to compose rich models using classes than it ever was using ES5 of lower.

Answer (score -1):

One benefit is that you can write very clear, concise code in ES6 that would take many lines in ES5. Take for example:

**ES6:**

```
const PI = 3.141593
PI > 3.0
```

**ES5:**

```
Object.defineProperty(typeof global === "object" ? global : window, "PI", {
    value:        3.141593,
    enumerable:   true,
    writable:     false,
    configurable: false
})
PI > 3.0;
```

As you can see, they both accomplish the same thing, but the difference is a massive savings in time and cleaner code. Which would you prefer to code/maintain? The practice is almost exclusively for the developer, not the end user.

Credits to: http://es6-features.org/#Constants

Comment: Also, you want to write efficient and human-readable code, which es6 and es7 specifications greatly improves. So, even though not many js engines can "read" those specifications, they will some day, and you won't need to update your code

Comment: `const` variables do not become global properties.

Comment: Is this what Babel does in the conversion? I thought it would just substitute `var` and yell at you if it sees a reassignment.

Comment: [I just checked](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=const%20PI%20%3D%201.234%3B%0API%20%3D%2010%3B). That's exactly what it does. It just uses `var`. It also renames the variable to keep it in block scope if necessary.